# Changing configuration from publishing Dynamic CP to Broker DB

Tags: publishing, 5.3

I am living with a system where Dynamic CP are configured to published to the File System instead of the Broker DB. I would like to change this from File System to the Broker DB, but the catch is that, I do not want to to re-publish items.

I know, I can do this by changing configuration/storage ID in the Broker Configuration file, but I really do not want to publish the millions of the items for 100 of websites.

Is there some geek way out?

Comment: Sometime between R5.3 and 2009 or 2011, the way custom metadata was stored changed from comma separated values to key-value pairs. I wouldn't recommend going the route of a direct database script, but it's worth knowing the difference between versions (and there may be others).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the core of your goal, you need to move your millions of items sources from the filesystem into the database. You can either choose to do that using the tridion mechanisms (i.e. publishing), or you can write your own migration scripts that take the contents of the filesystem files and insert them into the correct DB tables. I would be very carefull in choosing the latter because you have to take great care in ensuring that your DCPs are able to enter and exit the database without destroying for instance your encoding setup. Personally, i would be happier scripting the republish then i would be scripting the database inserts.

Comment: Thanks Rogier for sharing your thoughts. It is quite helpful.